# In an infinite geometric sequence the fourth term is 18, what is the smallest possible sum of all the terms?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

> In an infinite geometric sequence the fourth term is 18, what is the smallest possible sum of all the terms?

**My steps**

If $s=\frac{a}{1-r}$  we can do the following:

$$\frac{a}{1-r}*\frac{r^3}{r^3}=\frac{ar^3}{r^3-r^4}$$

and then we do substitution to get the following:

$$\frac{18}{r^3(1-r)}$$

so then I thought that in order to make the sum the smallest possible number we ought to make the denominator super small, so then I know that the "zeroes" of $r^3-r^4$ are $0$ & $1$ so then the minimum must be at when x=0.5 but then according to a "math genius" he said that I was wrong.

How do I actually go about solving this problem?

Comment: I like your method, but to make the number small, you need to make the denominator *large*. For example $\frac12 > \frac19$.

Comment: Does the problem say that all terms of the geometric sequence must be positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $|r| < 1$, and look at $f(r) = r^3 - r^4\implies f'(r) = 3r^2 - 4r^3 = r^2(3-4r) = 0 \iff r = 0,\frac{3}{4}=0.75$, and $f''(r) = 6r-12r^2\implies f''(0) = 0, f''(\frac{3}{4}) = -\dfrac{9}{4} < 0\implies r = \frac{3}{4}$ yields a maximum by the $2^{\text{nd}}$ derivative test $\implies S_{\text{min}} = \dfrac{18}{0.75^3 - 0.75^4}= ...$

Comment: The only *local* minimum (for the series sum) is at $r=\frac34$.What about $r\in(-1,0)?$  If we interpret "smallest" to mean "smallest absolute value" then the minimum seems to be $$-18+18-18+18+\cdots=-9$$ except for the technicality of divergence.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of $r^3-r^4$ on the interval $(0,1)$ is not at $1/2$. To find it, you can use calculus (solve $f'(x)=0$ where $f(x)=x^3-x^4$). Also, are you allowing $r$ to be negative? If you are, then for $r$ negative and near zero, the sum is dominated by the first term which is negative, and has large absolute value.

Comment: Maybe "smallest possible sum" means sum with smallest possible absolute value? For $r$ negative and near $-1$ the series has its smallest absolute value which is near $-9$.